# Required XML Attribute adSize error in admob?

Tags: android, xml, admob

im trying to ad admob in my app .
i imported google play services lib in project properties 
and i implemented the app like the guid but im gettin error of xml attribute adsize error

here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background2"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:shrinkColumns="50"
    android:stretchColumns="1" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="25dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/gt1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                android:text="@string/gt1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse"
                android:textColor="#FDD017"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/gt2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                android:text="@string/gt2"
                android:textColor="#FDD017"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/gt3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                android:text="@string/gt3"
                android:textColor="#FDD017"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="30dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/gt4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                android:text="@string/gt4"
                android:textColor="#FDD017"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/gt5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                android:text="@string/gt5"
                android:textColor="#FDD017"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/gt6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                android:text="@string/gt6"
                android:textColor="#FDD017"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="30dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/gt7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                android:text="@string/gt7"
                android:textColor="#FDD017"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/gt8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                android:text="@string/gt8"
                android:textColor="#FDD017"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/gt9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                android:text="@string/gt9"
                android:textColor="#FDD017"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="30dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/gt10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                android:text="@string/gt10"
                android:textColor="#FDD017"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/gt11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                android:text="@string/gt11"
                android:textColor="#FDD017"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxx" >
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

and here is where im putting adrequest in my code

```
AdView adView = (AdView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

my program has a three tabs if that info is needed

Comment: specify width and height of admob adview or change parent layout to linear

Comment: i changed parentlayout to linear layout but nothing happens what size should i gave the adview ?

Comment: width 320 x height 50

Comment: try putting adview at the top of the activity....just above the tablelayout

Comment: sorry no other option than i have

Comment: @Shink tnx man but i think i found where problem is i tried to set test device ads:testDevices="0140A63A1C9CF10B8F28288289178145" then i get this error 
No resource identifier found for attribute 'testDevices' in package 'com.safshari.board3den'

Comment: i think problem is somthing withmy packege or xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" any ideas @Shink ?

Comment: Post the actual error you are getting.

Comment: i found the answer its a bug you should close eclipse and reopen it ! if u want type this as answer so i can pick your answer as good answer and you earn some points @william

Comment: thanks, close and reopen eclipse is the answer